# Prepositions in, on and at rules

Tags: prepositions, in-on-at

I would like to know when to use each one of them. I mean, how is the right way to use in and on.

Example:

> The gift is **in** or **on** the box

And *in* and *on* are similar, but *at* is different. Anyway i read some uses of *at*, where it sounds like *in* or *on*. What makes it different from others? What are the rules to use each one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are asking the *rules,* I'm afraid, it'll be too broad here to describe. However, in the context of the sentence in concern, I can give you some idea. You would be, possibly, able to determine the use of prepositions then.

> The gift is *in* the box - You have to open the box or at least take out that gift from the box. In short, if the box is *not* transparent, you cannot see the gift. It is inside the box.
>
> The gift is *on* the box - Probably, the gift is lying *on* the box. Imagine a gift *on* the table which means the gift is lying *on* the table. In the same way, the gift is *on* the box i.e. on the *surface* of box.

*At* talks about the place the thing/person is at. For instance, *I'm at office* means your location is office. In this sense, *The gift is at the box* will be bad English.

Another important rule in the context of *time* is...

> Use *on* to indicate date or day - The party is ***on*** Tuesday 
>   Use *in* for the month - My birthday is ***in*** October 
>  Use *at* for the hours - I'll meet you ***at*** 6 o'clock.

Comment: When we use `in time` and `at time` and `on time` ? What's the core difference or any rule ?

Comment: Someone *in time* means *within* the time specified. Someone *at time* is ungrammatical. Someone *on time* is exactly on the time specified. The train is *on time*; For international flights, you should reach airport *in time.* '[At time](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/at+time)' is all different in this context.